# How to retrieve azure security groups in c#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory

I am trying to retrieve a list of users from an azure security group, however i am having trouble with this, as i do not know the best possible and easy way to do this in c#. Any help/direction and sample code would be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve list of users from an azure security group, make sure to grant the below **API permission**:

[image]

Please try using the below script by **Jason Pan** in this [***SO Thread***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69339938/get-members-of-a-security-group-from-azure-ad-via-microsoft-graph) like below:

```cs
 public async Task<JsonResult> sample()
    {
        var clientId = Your_Client_ID;
        var clientSecret = Your_Client_Secret;
        var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
        var tenantId = Your_Tenant_ID;
        var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
        {
            AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
        };
            var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
            tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);
            var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
        try
        {
            var members = await graphClient.Groups["Your_Group_ID"].Members.Request().GetAsync();
            return Json(members);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return Json("");
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: i noticed in the scopes variable you have a url - is this correct or does some other value need to be inserted in there?

Comment: Yes, the value is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Microsoft Graph restful web APIs to access microsoft cloud resources .
It has api endpoints for groups , users etc.
In your case you can use list groups endpoint to fetch the groups.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/group?view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: how do i authenticate first? what should i supply in the request body?

Comment: For postman [link]https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-postman?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0 this will help ...  For code what you need is create a GraphServiceClient and use same . This client would need same ClientId and Secret as mentioned in bove link

Comment: in C#, namespace needed using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Auth;  and you can register client like below :-   services.AddSingleton<IGraphServiceClient, GraphServiceClient>(provider =>
                new GraphServiceClient(new ClientCredentialProvider(ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                    .Create("AppClientId")
                    .WithTenantId("TenantId")
                    .WithClientSecret("AppClientSecret")

Comment: I'm using the code above and making use of the Microsoft.Graph namespace - however it keeps saying that an error has occurred while sending request. I'm not sure why i have checked the credentials and also set up permissions for the api on azure end,...

Comment: Can you try via postman if your credentials are working or not?